# How do I adjust for the thinning effect of FakeStretch with a subtle amount of boldness?

Tags: fontspec

I want to make my squished font a little bolder: I have a font that is a little wider than it needs to be, and I'm making it 12.5% thinner:

```
    \setmainfont[FakeStretch=0.875]{\myfontname}
```

One of the side-effects of this is that the stroke appears 15% lighter (ie. it's kinda grey when printed, rather than black).  I'd like to correct that with FakeBold, but its working seems to be unsubtle, as if it's only made for whole numbers:

```
    \setmainfont[FakeBold=0.15, FakeStretch=0.875]{\myfontname}
```

FakeBold values from 0.15 to 1.4 seem to do pretty much the same thing - a bit too much boldness.  Is there a correct way to simply make the text that little bit wider?